# Uncaught TypeError: nav.classList.togle is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, browser-cache

I am trying to execute this javascript to show one head menu, but when I execute it, the browser responds that "Uncaught TypeError: nav.classList.togle is not a function", the function is right "toggle", but the message that I get when I try to find the error using F12 is considering the spell with "togle". There is any way to fix it at the browser interpretation?

```
/*abre e fecha o menu quando clicar no icone: hamburguer e x*/
const nav = document.querySelector('#header nav')
const toggle = document.querySelectorAll('nav .toggle')

for (const element of toggle) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    nav.classList.toggle('show')
  })
}

/*quando clicar em um item do menu, esconder o menu*/
const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a')

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function () {
    nav.classList.remove('show')
  })
}

/*mudar o header da página quando der scroll*/
const header = document.querySelector('#header')
const navHeight = header.offsetHeight

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (window.scrollY >= navHeight) {
    // scroll é maior que a altura do header
    header.classList.add('scroll')
  } else {
    // menor que a altura do header
    header.classList.remove('scroll')
  }
})
```

Comment: There is no possible explanation save that somewhere in your code is `nav.classList.togle`. Do a global search on all your project files

Answer (score 0):

The below querySelector is not correctly finding an element.

`const nav = document.querySelector('#header nav')`

Since you are targeting the element by `id`, perhaps consider simplifying to

```
const nav = document.querySelector('#header')
console.log(nav) // Ensure this is returning an element
```